# Minimum number of squares

Tags: c++

There is a problem that states:

> John has a piece of paper with NxM dimensions, he wants to cut it into
> 1x1 squares, with the rules:he can cut the piece of paper only once at
> a certain time,  every cut has to go all the way around the paper

This is the code for it:

```
int n , m;
cin >> n >> m;
cout << (n - 1) + 1LL * n * (m - 1);
```

Can somebody explain why do you solve it like this?

Comment: What the problem requires as the result?

Comment: @Austin I know, but usually problems like this requires a result, such as "Calculate the number of cuts John must do in the paper" or "Calculate many 1x1 squares John can make by cutting the paper". Maybe that confused me.

Comment: the number of cuts is the required answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my understanding of the question based on the answer:

- You cut the paper into N equal length pieces. Each has a length of 1 and width of M. This requires (N-1) cuts.
- For each of these N sheets, you cut them into M equal pieces which have 1 width and 1 length. This requires (M-1) for each sheet so, N * (M-1) in total.

Therefore the result is (N-1) + N * (M-1)

Comment: Oh my god, that's it, thank you so much brother!!!

Comment: @kiddoP You can accept the answer if it answers your question. (You have to select the green checkmark to the left of the answer.)

Answer (score 0):

I have not figure out the question until I saw the answer by @mkemaltas.

Now, you can simplify that formula `(N-1) + N * (M-1)` to `N * M - 1`.

A comment about `1LL *...` in the question: if `M * N` is greater that maximum `int` value - you will get an integer overflow. By adding that `long long int` into the expression, you are converting everything to `long long`, avoiding that possible overflow.

Comment: yeah i know about the overflow error, that wasn't the point, the problem is that when i used the N*M-1 formula something went wrong and I didn't get all the points on the exercise so therefore i was confused as to why one gives more points than the other, but @mkemaltas came in really helpful. Never the less, thank you as well for answering!!

Comment: @kiddoP Well, did you do `1LL*N*M-1`?